# Array of hashes problems

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

If I have the following data

```
First Name =>, Last Name, Age, Income, Household Size, Gender, Education
Jon, Smith, 25, 50000, 1, Male, College
Jane, Davies, 30, 60000, 3, Female, High School
Sam, Farelly, 32, 80000, 2, Unspecified, College
Joan, Favreau, 35, 65000, 4, Female, College
Sam, McNulty, 38, 63000, 3, Male, College
Mark, Minahan, 48, 78000, 5, Male, High School
Susan, Umani, 45, 75000, 2, Female, College
Bill, Perault, 24, 45000, 1, Male, Did Not Complete High School
Doug, Stamper, 45, 75000, 1, Male, College
Francis, Underwood, 52, 100000, 2, Male, College
```

and I want to create an array of hashes to answer the following questions
 Average age
 Average income 
Average household size
 Female Percentage
 Male Percentage
 Unspecified Gender Percentage
 Percent of those who obtained a college education level Percent of those who obtained a high school education level
Percent of those that did not finish high school

Would I be able to organize  the data in this way

```
voter_demographics = [
  {
    :firstname => ["Jon", "Jane", "Sam", "Joan", "Sam", "Mark", "Susan", "Bill", "Doug", "Francis"],
    :lastname => ["Smith", "Davies", "Farelly", "Favreau", "McNulty", "Minahan", "Umani", "Perault", "Stamper", "Underwood"],
    :age => [25, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 45, 24, 45, 52],
    :income => [50000, 60000, 80000, 65000, 63000, 78000, 75000, 45000, 75000, 100000],
    :household_size => [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    :gender => ["male", "female", "unspecified", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male"],
    :education => ["college", "high school", "college", "college", "college", "high school", "college", "did not complete high school", "college", "college"]
  }
]
```

If someone could just help me get started on question one(Average age ). Im still struggling on hashes and how to call out each data.

```
For the first question ; Find Average age. Would the following work.
sum = 0
voter_demographics.each do |:age|
sum = sum + :age 
average = sum / :age.length
puts "The average is #{average}".
```

Im stuck on this. 
And if there are any resources for beginners you could recommend on hashes and array of hashes that would be great!

Comment: `voter_demographics.first[:age].instance_eval { inject(:+) / size }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we can emphasize with the task of learning, it's _REALLY_ important that you try, then try again, and continue until you can't try any longer when dealing with homework or self-assigned learning. "[ask]", "[mcve]", “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why you have `voter_demographics` as an array.  If you remove the square brackets then it would just be a hash, like this:

```
voter_demographics = {
  :firstname => ["Jon", "Jane", "Sam", "Joan", "Sam", "Mark", "Susan", "Bill", "Doug", "Francis"],
  :lastname => ["Smith", "Davies", "Farelly", "Favreau", "McNulty", "Minahan", "Umani", "Perault", "Stamper", "Underwood"],
  :age => [25, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 45, 24, 45, 52],
  :income => [50000, 60000, 80000, 65000, 63000, 78000, 75000, 45000, 75000, 100000],
  :household_size => [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2],
  :gender => ["male", "female", "unspecified", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male"],
  :education => ["college", "high school", "college", "college", "college", "high school", "college", "did not complete high school", "college", "college"]
}
```

Then you can access values in the hash like this:

```
voter_demographics[:age]
```

And finding your average would work like this:

```
voter_demographics[:age].inject(:+).to_f / voter_demographics[:age].size
```

or

```
ages = voter_demographics[:age]
ages.inject(:+).to_f / ages.size
```

The `.to_f` assumes you want a float number back, so my solutions would give you **37.4** instead of **37**

Another solution would be to just use regular variables instead of a hash:

```
firstnames = ["Jon", "Jane", "Sam", "Joan", "Sam", "Mark", "Susan", "Bill", "Doug", "Francis"],
lastnames = ["Smith", "Davies", "Farelly", "Favreau", "McNulty", "Minahan", "Umani", "Perault", "Stamper", "Underwood"],
ages = [25, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 45, 24, 45, 52],
incomes = [50000, 60000, 80000, 65000, 63000, 78000, 75000, 45000, 75000, 100000],
household_sizes = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2],
genders = ["male", "female", "unspecified", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male"],
educations = ["college", "high school", "college", "college", "college", "high school", "college", "did not complete high school", "college", "college"]
```

Then this would work:

```
ages.inject(:+).to_f / ages.size
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keys, *data =<<_.split(/\n/).map { |line| line.split /,\s+/ }
First Name, Last Name, Age, Income, Household Size, Gender, Education
Jon, Smith, 25, 50000, 1, Male, College
Jane, Davies, 30, 60000, 3, Female, High School
Sam, Farelly, 32, 80000, 2, Unspecified, College
Joan, Favreau, 35, 65000, 4, Female, College
Sam, McNulty, 38, 63000, 3, Male, College
Mark, Minahan, 48, 78000, 5, Male, High School
Susan, Umani, 45, 75000, 2, Female, College
Bill, Perault, 24, 45000, 1, Male, Did Not Complete High School
Doug, Stamper, 45, 75000, 1, Male, College
Francis, Underwood, 52, 100000, 2, Male, College
_
```

We now have the following values for `keys` and `data`.

```
keys
  #=> ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age", "Income", "Household Size",
  #    "Gender", "Education"] 
data
  #=> [["Jon", "Smith", "25", "50000", "1", "Male", "College"],
  #    ["Jane", "Davies", "30", "60000", "3", "Female", "High School"],
  #    ["Sam", "Farelly", "32", "80000", "2", "Unspecified", "College"],
  #    ["Joan", "Favreau", "35", "65000", "4", "Female", "College"],
  #    ["Sam", "McNulty", "38", "63000", "3", "Male", "College"],
  #    ["Mark", "Minahan", "48", "78000", "5", "Male", "High School"],
  #    ["Susan", "Umani", "45", "75000", "2", "Female", "College"],
  #    ["Bill", "Perault", "24", "45000", "1", "Male", "Did Not Complete High School"],
  #    ["Doug", "Stamper", "45", "75000", "1", "Male", "College"],
  #    ["Francis", "Underwood", "52", "100000", "2", "Male", "College"]]
```

Next create the following hash.

```
h = keys.zip(data.transpose).to_h
  #=> {"First Name"    =>["Jon", "Jane", "Sam", "Joan", "Sam", "Mark", "Susan",
  #                       "Bill", "Doug", "Francis"],
  #    "Last Name"     =>["Smith", "Davies", "Farelly", "Favreau", "McNulty", "Minahan",
  #                       "Umani", "Perault", "Stamper", "Underwood"],
  #    "Age"           =>["25", "30", "32", "35", "38", "48", "45", "24", "45", "52"],
  #    "Income"        =>["50000", "60000", "80000", "65000", "63000", "78000",
  #                      "75000", "45000", "75000", "100000"],
  #    "Household Size"=>["1", "3", "2", "4", "3", "5", "2", "1", "1", "2"],
  #    "Gender"        =>["Male", "Female", "Unspecified", "Female", "Male", "Male",
  #                       "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male"],
  #    "Education"     =>["College", "High School", "College", "College", "College",
  #                       "High School", "College", "Did Not Complete High School",
  #                       "College", "College"]}
```

It is now simple to compute the various statistics.

```
n = arr.size.to_f
  #=> 10.0

avg_age = h["Age"].map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)/n.to_f
  #=> 37.4 
avg_income = h["Income"].map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)/n.to_f
  #=> 69100.0 
avg_hsize = h["Household Size"].map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)/n.to_f
  #=> 2.4 
pct_female= 100*h["Gender"].count("Female")/n.to_f
  #=> 30.0
```

and so on.

*Computing other statistics*

Now suppose you wished to compute statistics that involved multiple keys, such as the average age of females. The easiest way to do that (as well as computing the simple averages and percentages) is to put the data in a database and use SQL queries. However, we can also to that by first creating an array of hashes.

```
arr = data.map { |row| keys.zip(row).to_h }
  #=> [{"First Name"=>"Jon", "Last Name"=>"Smith", "Age"=>"25", "Income"=>"50000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"1", "Gender"=>"Male", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Jane", "Last Name"=>"Davies", "Age"=>"30", "Income"=>"60000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"3", "Gender"=>"Female", "Education"=>"High School"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Sam", "Last Name"=>"Farelly", "Age"=>"32", "Income"=>"80000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"2", "Gender"=>"Unspecified", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Joan", "Last Name"=>"Favreau", "Age"=>"35", "Income"=>"65000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"4", "Gender"=>"Female", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Sam", "Last Name"=>"McNulty", "Age"=>"38", "Income"=>"63000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"3", "Gender"=>"Male", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Mark", "Last Name"=>"Minahan", "Age"=>"48", "Income"=>"78000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"5", "Gender"=>"Male", "Education"=>"High School"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Susan", "Last Name"=>"Umani", "Age"=>"45", "Income"=>"75000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"2", "Gender"=>"Female", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Bill", "Last Name"=>"Perault", "Age"=>"24", "Income"=>"45000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"1", "Gender"=>"Male",
  #     "Education"=>"Did Not Complete High School"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Doug", "Last Name"=>"Stamper", "Age"=>"45", "Income"=>"75000",
  #     "Household Size"=>"1", "Gender"=>"Male", "Education"=>"College"},
  #    {"First Name"=>"Francis", "Last Name"=>"Underwood", "Age"=>"52",
  #     "Income"=>"100000", "Household Size"=>"2", "Gender"=>"Male",
  #     "Education"=>"College"}]
```

Then to compute the average age of females, create an array of ages for females, then sum its elements and divide that sum by the size of the array.

```
a = arr.each_with_object([]) { |h,a| a << h["Age"].to_i if h["Gender"]=="Female" }
  #=> [30, 35, 45]
a.empty? ? 0.0 : a.reduce(:+)/a.size.to_f
  #=> 36.666666666666664
```

Other calculations are similar.

Answer (score 0):

your `voter_demographics` is an array with only one element

```
voter_demographics[0]
=> {:firstname=>["Jon", "Jane", "Sam", "Joan", "Sam", "Mark", "Susan", "Bill", "Doug", "Francis"], :lastname=>["Smith", "Davies", "Farelly", "Favreau", "McNulty", "Minahan", "Umani", "Perault", "Stamper", "Underwood"], :age=>[25, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 45, 24, 45, 52], :income=>[50000, 60000, 80000, 65000, 63000, 78000, 75000, 45000, 75000, 100000], :household_size=>[1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2], :gender=>["male", "female", "unspecified", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male"], :education=>["college", "high school", "college", "college", "college", "high school", "college", "did not complete high school", "college", "college"]}
voter_demographics[1]
=> nil
```

So, let's take the first element and get the age data:

```
age_data = voter_demographics[0][:age]
=> [25, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 45, 24, 45, 52]
```

Now, we can sum the data

```
sum = 0
age_data.each { |e| sum = sum + e }
sum
=> 374
```

or just

```
age_data.inject(:+)
=> 374
```

You can also get the number of elements

```
age_data.size
=> 10
```

Finally

```
age_data.inject(:+)/age_data.size
=> 37
```

I hope it helps you understanding it ;)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, how to organize your data into `voter_demographics`, you can use a csv parser in ruby. So, save the data in a `file.csv` format, and parse it.

```
require 'csv'

csv_data = CSV.parse(File.read('file1.csv'), headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)

data_array = csv_data.map {|arr| arr.to_h}
```

Now, we have an array of hashes like

```
[{:first_name=>"Jon", :last_name=>" Smith", :age=>" 25", :income=>" 50000", :household_size=>" 1", :gender=>" Male", :education=>" College"},
{:first_name=>"Jane", :last_name=>" Davies", :age=>" 30", :income=>" 60000", :household_size=>" 3", :gender=>" Female", :education=>" High School"},
...]
```

Now, we can write something to format this data into your desired format.

```
result = {}

data_array[0].each do |k, v|
    result[k] = data_array.map {|hash| hash[k].strip }   
end
```

The other answers already answered the second part of your question, so I won't do it again here.